# Generating random dates between start date and end date in utc format using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, random, momentjs

How can i generate random dates between two dates in utc format using javascript?
example: start date is 23-01-25 02:07:04 and end date is 23-02-25 02:07:04
I want a list of random dates between start date & end date as below:
[23-01-26 02:07:04,23-02-02 02:07:04,.....]

This is my Javasxript code:

```js
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

const d = randomDate(new Date(2023, 04, 01), new Date(2023, 04, 12));
console.log(d);
```

But it gives wrong output:

```
2023-05-08T17:09:26.445Z
```

Can anyone suggest me a proper way to get solution

Comment: What makes the output "wrong"? Looks OK to me. (Note that months are numbered from 0 in JavaScript dates, so your code is asking for a random date at the start of the month May.)

Comment: Months start with `0` in js. `11` is december

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date: _"monthIndex:
Integer value representing the month, **beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.**"_ - you created a start and end date that are both in _May_ of 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, months in JavaScript are indexed from 0-11.

See: [`Date.prototype.setMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)

> `monthValue`
> An integer representing the month: 0 for January, 1 for February, and so on.

```js
const
  startDate = new Date(2023, 4, 1), // 2023-05-01
  endDate = new Date(2023, 4, 12);  // 2023-05-12

// Generate 1 million random dates between the provided range...
for (let i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
  const randomDate = getRandomDate(startDate, endDate);
  if (randomDate < startDate || startDate > endDate) {
    throw new Error(`Date out of range: ${randomDate}`);
  }
}

// Should get here if there are no range errors...
console.log('No errors...');

function getRandomDate(startDate, endDate) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
    startDate = new Date();
  }
  return new Date(getRandomInt(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime()));
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  if (arguments.length === 1) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should convert the dates to the time format and calculate a random number in the range of two numbers.

```js
function randomDate(start, end){
  var start_date_arr = start.split('-');
  if(start_date_arr[0].length == 2){
     start_date_arr[0] = '20' + start_date_arr[0]
  }
  var start_date = new Date(start_date_arr[0], start_date_arr[1] - 1, start_date_arr[2].substr(0, 2), start_date_arr[2].substr(3, 2), start_date_arr[2].substr(6, 2), start_date_arr[2].substr(9, 2));
  var start_time = start_date.getTime();

  var end_date_arr = end.split('-');
  if(end_date_arr[0].length == 2){
     end_date_arr[0] = '20' + end_date_arr[0]
  }
  var end_date = new Date(end_date_arr[0], end_date_arr[1] - 1, end_date_arr[2].substr(0, 2), end_date_arr[2].substr(3, 2), end_date_arr[2].substr(6, 2), end_date_arr[2].substr(9, 2));
  var end_time = end_date.getTime();


  var random_time = Math.floor(Math.random() * (end_time - start_time + 1)) + start_time;
  var random_date = new Date(random_time);

  console.log([start, end, random_date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')]);
  return random_date;
}

 randomDate('23-01-25 02:07:04', '23-02-25 02:07:04');
```